# Linux : launch a specific action when another process is terminated

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I Have a script `foo.sh` that launches 5 process of `bfoo.sh` in background like this :

```
for i in {1..5}
do 
  ./bfoo.sh &
done 
wait 
echo ok
```

and I use it like this :

```
./foo.sh
```

In `foo.s` after the for loop, I want to do something like i.e. for each process `bfoo.sh` terminated do

```
echo $PID_Terminated
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this, you need to store the PID of each of the background process of `bfoo.sh`. The `$!` contains the process id that was last backgrounded by the shell. We append them one at a time to the array and iterate it over later

Remember this runs your background process one after the other since you have `wait` on each process id separately.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

pidArray=()

for i in {1..5}; do 
    ./bfoo.sh &
    pidArray+=( "$!" )
done
```

Now wait on each of the processes and in a loop

```
for pid in "${pidArray[@]}"; do
    wait "$pid"
    printf 'process-id: %d finished with code %d\n' "$pid" "$?"
done
```

I have additionally added the exit code of the background process `$?` when it finishes, so that any abnormal exit can be debugged.